# LASSO fit scikit-learn - obtain likelihood

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm using LASSO from scikit-learn package to optimize the parameters of a penalized linear regression problem. I'm not only interested in the optimal choice of parameters, but also in the likelihood of the data with respect to the optimized parameters. Is there an easy way to get the full likelihood after fitting?

Comment: What do you mean by *optimized parameters*? With respect to what metric? Prediction score?

Answer (score 1):

It is slightly deceiving to consider the `lasso` in a maximum likelihood framework. The prior distribution on the coefficients is then a laplacian distribution `exp(-np.prod(np.abs(coef)))`, which yields sparsity only as an "artifact" at its optimum. The probability of obtaining a sparse sample from this distribution is 0 (it happens "almost never").

This disclaimer out of the way, you can write

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
est = Lasso(alpha=10.)
est.fit(X, y)
coef = est.coef_
data_loss = 0.5 * ((X.dot(coef) - y) ** 2).sum()
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
penalty = n_samples * est.alpha * np.abs(coef).sum()
likelihood = np.exp(-(data_loss + penalty))
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'll need some more time to think through my problem before I can give a useful feedback on your answer. My current problem is that the alpha contains two parameters: The variance of the normal distribution and the "tightness" of the prior on the fitted parameters.

Comment: The parameter `alpha` only regulates the "prior" on the weights. Which normal distribution are you referring to? The distribution of the residuals? Because the weights, according to this "prior", are not normally distributed

Comment: To my understanding: the posterior is N(y | mu=y_hat, sigma^2) * La(w_t, mu=0, tau). The first term belongs to the ordinary linear regression, where y is the vector of the observed values, y_hat the vector of linear combinations of the seen data and the weights (normal distribution). The second term is the Laplacian prior. Alpha is proportional to sigma^2 / tau. When optimizing the weights, sigma and tau are not so important and the combined term alpha regulates the strength of the regularization. My current problem is, that I think I need both sigma and tau to calculate the full posterior.

Comment: sorry, w_t in the Laplace Prior should have been just w and is the weight vector.

Comment: I may be totally wrong, but I think `alpha` is your `tau`. An estimate of `sigma^2` can be obtained through the residual. I'd be very interested in a formal derivation of this if you find any. NB: If you want a real sparsity prior to go the bayesian way, usually you choose spike + slab.

Comment: How can you implement a spike-and-slab prior in Python?